# I am struggling to make sense of this xml like data

Tags: xml, flash, xml-parsing

I have been tasked with rewriting the ui elements of a Flash web app. The data comes back in two forms from the servers cgi scripts. 1. I make a request and get back traditional XML. I can use and XML parsing package to transform this into JSON. 2. I get an xml'ish return where the data is inline sort of like inline html.

```
<bannergroups>
  <bannergroup data="" label=""/>
  <bannergroup data="85" label="Closed Stores"/>
  <bannergroup data="78" label="Daly City Lucky"/>
  <bannergroup data="81" label="FM District 10"/>
</bannergroups>
```

Can I parse this data somehow with Javascript? I get other errors, but I don't want to dive too deeply into it if I just need to rewrite the backend instead. Can anyone direct me to more information on this type of XML that would be helpfull also.

Comment: I should add that I am using Vue.js on my frontend. I do get the response I have above but in my vue data property, it is undefined. Presumably, since I am using an xml parser that does not know what this response is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly ordinary and well-formed XML, what exactly is your problem with it?

I guess perhaps you haven't come across XML that uses attributes before? There's nothing very unusual about them.

- `bannergroups` is an element that has child elements
- `bannergroup` is an empty element that has attributes
- `data` and `label` are attributes

All standard XML tools, such as XML parsers, XSLT, and XPath, will handle this without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I haven't worked with XML much, so it seemed too different to me. Good to know though.

Comment: So what I am fighting seems to be some kind of error from my the backend, or xml parser I am using. I am using xml2js, I get an error from that "[native Error Invalid character in entity name\nLine: 22\nColumn: 41\nChar:  ]"  This is line 22 of the response. <bannergroup data="63" label="NI Plus & Lucky"  /> I'm not really sure but at least we ruled out the format of data being the culpret.

Comment: Ampersands in XML must always be written `&amp;`, so it should be `Plus &amp; Lucky`. Seems the person who generated this doesn't know much about XML either.